# Debezium does not capture 'cascade delete'

Tags: debezium

Is there any way to capture 'on delete cascade' events?
I have read in the [Debezium faq](https://debezium.io/docs/faq/) (at the bottom of the page):

> == Why don't I see DELETE events in some cases?
>
> This may be caused by the usage of `CASCADE DELETE` statements. In
>   this case the deletion events generated by the database
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-and-mysql-replication.html [are
>   not part of the binlog] and thus cannot be captured by Debezium.

I appreciate a similar behaviour with 'ON UPDATE CASCADE'

If that events are not part of the binlog I understand that Debezium cannot capture it but, Is there any easy alternative way to do it? In a database this is very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I can think about is to replace cascade operations with triggers that will execute the delete/update as needed.